# Next.js Server Error: The edge runtime does not support Node.js 'stream' module

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I'm running Next.js in a local environment / docker compose with mongodb.

I'm currently setting up the auth and middleware.

In my `auth.config.ts` that is used in used in the `middleware.ts` as `const { auth } = NextAuth(authConfig);`, I have this

async `authorize(credentials)` function that handles Credentials as the Provider:

```
import bcrypt from "bcryptjs";
import type { NextAuthConfig } from "next-auth";
import Credentials from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import Github from "next-auth/providers/github";
import Google from "next-auth/providers/google";

import { LoginSchema } from "@/models";
import { getUserByEmail } from "@/data/user";

export default {
 providers: [
  Google(...),
  Github(...),
  Credentials({
   async authorize(credentials) {
        const validatedFields = LoginSchema.safeParse(credentials);

        if (validatedFields.success) {
          const { email, password } = validatedFields.data;
          
          const user = await getUserByEmail(email);
          if (!user || !user.password) return null;

          const passwordsMatch = await bcrypt.compare(
            password,
            user.password,
          );

          if (passwordsMatch) return user;
        }

        return null;
      }
  })
 ]
}
```

I'm getting this stacktrace:

```
Server Error
Error: The edge runtime does not support Node.js 'stream' module.
Learn More: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/node-module-in-edge-runtime

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Call Stack
<unknown>
webpack-internal:///(middleware)/./node_modules/next/dist/esm/server/web/globals.js (33)
Object.get
webpack-internal:///(middleware)/./node_modules/next/dist/esm/server/web/globals.js (33:19)
eval
webpack-internal:///(middleware)/./node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor/abstract_cursor.js (617:45)
(middleware)/./node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor/abstract_cursor.js
file:///home/loki/projects/nextjs/fire-project/fire-dashboard/.next/server/src/middleware.js (864:1)
__webpack_require__
file:///home/loki/projects/nextjs/fire-project/fire-dashboard/.next/server/edge-runtime-webpack.js (37:33)
fn
file:///home/loki/projects/nextjs/fire-project/fire-dashboard/.next/server/edge-runtime-webpack.js (280:21)
eval
webpack-internal:///(middleware)/./node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor/aggregation_cursor.js (9:27)
(middleware)/./node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor/aggregation_cursor.js
file:///home/loki/projects/nextjs/fire-project/fire-dashboard/.next/server/src/middleware.js (875:1)
__webpack_require__
file:///home/loki/projects/nextjs/fire-project/fire-dashboard/.next/server/edge-runtime-webpack.js (37:33)
fn
file:///home/loki/projects/nextjs/fire-project/fire-dashboard/.next/server/edge-runtime-webpack.js (280:21)
eval
webpack-internal:///(middleware)/./node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js (10:30)
```

I'm explicitly using `bcryptjs` to avoid `bcrypt` using `stream`.

When I comment out the `authorize` function, this error disappears.

What am I doing wrong?

Do I even need 'edge' runtime, when I want to deploy it on docker, and where can I change that?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some edge runtime issue when you are using database as a session strategy. One of the solution is use jwt strategy instead of database for session handling with next auth! look at https://blog.stackademic.com/authentication-and-authorization-on-the-edge-with-auth-js-nextauth-5-and-mongodb-5903d7e95f99